# How to reload UIViewController from another Controller in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 controllers A and Controller B . Controller A has a TableView and Controller B is a subview that when clicked opens a form and on Submit it enters data into the database. I want to reload my TableView from Controller B from the user hits submit.

Controller A

````
  func btnQTYClickedFromcell(selectedIP: IndexPath) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Dashboard", bundle: nil)
        let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnterQTYView")
        myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    ```

popup(Controller B) will appear.after click on submit button ,get a dictionary as a response.

I want to update my Controller A with that response.

how should I do?Please Help
````

Comment: you can used "create delegate" and also used "local notification".

Comment: Why you don't reload when `viewWillAppear` calls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a simple  notification

Add this on submit button action (Controller A)

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("reloadTable"), object: nil)
```

add this Controller B viewdidload()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(
self.reloadMyTable(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("reloadTable"),
object: nil)
}
```

Now add this function somewhere on Controller B

```
@objc func reloadMyTable(notification: Notification) {

 self.Table.reloadData()

/// Table is IBoutlet name of your tableview
}
```

**OR You can use** on Controller B

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.Table.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Custom Delegate // Make a custom Delegate

  ```
  protocol CustomDelegate {
     func response(_ res:Dictionary)
  }
  ```
- In VC2

  ```
  class VC2 : UIViewController {

     var delegate : CustomDelegate?
     var resp : Dictionary? //which comes on click on button

     ... //Your code 

     @IBAction func submitButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.response(resp ?? [:])
     }
  }
  ```
- VC1

  ```
  class VC1 : UIViewController {
  ......
  //MARK:- Delegate
     func response(_ res:Dictionary) {

     //Customize "res" as per your need.
     // reload your tableView
     tableView.reloadData()
     }
  }
  .....
  func btnQTYClickedFromcell(selectedIP: IndexPath) {

      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Dashboard", bundle: nil)
      let vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2 identifier")
      .......
      vc2.delegate = self
      self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
  ```